# Extract text between two characters multiple times on multiple lines in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to find an easy way to extract text between characters multiple times within the same cell. So in the example below, I want to take the information between the parenthesis and get them into the adjacent column, as shown. Is there a fast way to do this?

My process has been to use Text to Columns to separate them out into different cells, then use a mid function to get what's between the parenthesis, and string them all back together. I'm wondering if someone can think of a better way to do this. Thank you!

I should note-- I want to do this entirely within excel.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried FIND() .. and then combine it with MID()... ?

Comment: Yes-- this allows me to get the first line in each cell, but not the subsequent lines. So in the example above the second columns would only have [123] [789] [012]

Comment: Very much so possible with FILTERXML

Comment: =MID(LEFT(A15,FIND(")",A15)-1),FIND("(",A15)+1,LEN(A15))

Comment: How many maximum parenthesis per box did you anticipate?

Comment: 15 is probably the max

Answer (score 1):

For example:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),1,LEFT(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1," (",CHAR(10)),CHAR(10),"</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[substring(.,1,3)*0=0]"),3))
```

Enter as array!

If you are interested in `FILTERXML`, you might want to have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61837696/9758194).

Comment: Shame, I suppose your Excel does not yet support TEXTJOIN. You could still access the resulting Filterxml array through Index,  bit no longer in the same cell. I'll have a look tomorrow. Can you tell me your version of Excel?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the 1st data is in A1, put :

```
=REPLACE(A1,1,FIND("(",A1),"") in C1
```

then,

```
=IFERROR(REPLACE(C1,FIND(")",C1),FIND("(",C1)-FIND(")",C1)+1," "),C1) in D1
```

and drag D1 to Q1. lastly, put

```
=Q1 in B1.
```

That shall do it.

Idea : replace all text between the ) & ( with a space, 15 times.

hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you! I think this is getting closer... using those formulas gave me this output. B2: 123 456)     C2: 789)     D2: 012 345 456)

Comment: you may click on the tick to remove this from 'unanswered' question list (if it solves..).. If it is not.. share the thoughts.. ( ;

Comment: Not there yet... I'm still getting the end ")" in the cell, and the numbers are not appearing on different lines in the cell

Comment: "appearing on different lines" needs a special character. I don't how to inset it in this formula.. | "...getting the end ")" in the cell " > do  `=MID(Q1,1,FIND(")",Q1)-1)` in B1